# how to make small multiple box plots with long data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a long data frame like the simplified sample below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data={'nm':['A','B']*12,'var':['vol','vol','ratio','ratio','price','price']*4,'value':np.random.randn(24)}
sample=pd.DataFrame(data)
sample
```

And wish to create small multiple box plots using var as facet, nm as category and value as value, how can I do so using matplotlib or seaborn? I've searched for similar code but the examples looked complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can start with seaborns `catplot`:

```
sns.catplot(x='nm', y='value', col='var', kind='box', data=sample)
```

[image]